# How to do ssh X forwarding to second X server?

Tags: ssh, cygwin, xserver

I started two xservers: `xwin.exe :0` and `xwin.exe :1`

If I do `ssh -X remotehost` then `xterm` opens on first X server.

How to make `xterm` open on second X server?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have cygwin xserver to test now, but you can try :

```
DISPLAY=:1 ssh -X remotehost
```

or

```
DISPLAY=hostname:1 ssh -X remotehost
```